# Generate scale-free network with fixed minimum degree using igraph

Tags: igraph

I would like to generate a scale free network with 100 nodes and a minimum degree of 10.

Can this be done somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `degree.sequence.game` to create a graph with an arbitrary (graphical) degree sequence. So just create your degrees from whatever distribution you want and call this function.

Comment: so for example if I want a minimum of 10 contacts for each node, then I can do: degs <- sample(10:100, 100, replace=TRUE, prob=(10:100)^-2) and use this as an argument for the degree.sequence.game ?

Comment: Is it also possible to create a directed graph?

Comment: Yes, like that. It is also possible to create a directed graph, you need to supply two degree sequences, for in- and out-degrees, see the docs. Note that you always need to check that `degree.sequence.game()` succeeds, because some degree sequences are impossible to realize as a graph.

Comment: so how do I make the graph directed? I put the same argument for in and out-degree?

Comment: See http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/R/degree.sequence.game.html There are separate arguments for in-degree and out-degree. If you put in the same vector for both, for any vertex its out-degree will be equal to its in-degree.